# Is there an ASP.NET Core equivalent to OwinHttpConfigurationExtensions.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've come across `SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication` while investigating errors possibly caused by JavaScript requests to my application's API methods returning the wrong response code but it's for ASP.NET Web API 2.

**I'm looking for an equivalent in the converged (MVC + Web API) world of ASP.NET Core if one exists?**

> **SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication**
>
> When the host's default authentication is suppressed, the current principal is set to anonymous upon entering the HttpServer's first message handler. As a result, any default authentication performed by the host is ignored. The remaining pipeline within the HttpServer, including IAuthenticationFilters, is then the exclusive authority for authentication.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314641(v=vs.118).aspx
>
> While the MVC templates use a cookie based authentication mechanism,
>   the new SPA templates prefer to use a token based authentication model
>   explicitly passed via the Authorization HTTP header (which is better
>   since it avoids CSRF attacks). This means that the default
>   authentication from the host must be ignored since the authentication
>   will be performed against something else other than a cookie. Web API
>   2 added a feature to ignore the host level authentication called
>   SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication. This is an extension method on the
>   HttpConfiguration that adds a message handler. The purpose of this
>   message handler is to simply (and explicitly) assign an anonymous
>   principal to the RequestContext’s Principal property. This way if
>   cookie middleware does process an incoming cookie, by the time the
>   call arrives at Web API the caller will be treated as anonymous.
>
> https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is years late but it might help someone. I think what you are trying to do is mix cookie authentication (for a UI) with Jwt bearer token authentication on a Web Api. In times of old (4.x), you could SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication when you were setting up the web API to accomplish this. You can accomplish the same thing now by providing an authentication scheme to your authorize attribute on the Web API controller like so

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

You an read all about this in an example provided by Barry Dorrans here
[CookieJwtBearerExample](https://github.com/blowdart/CookieJwtBearerSample/tree/master/CookieJwtBearer)

Comment: OK, this is years later..., but you helped me... thanks for posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Brock Allen (author of IdentityServer) suggested:

`HttpContext.User = null`

I think he's saying that doing this in a handler would have the same effect but haven't had a chance to try it myself yet.

Source: https://twitter.com/BrockLAllen/status/829351328321302529